# Sqlite "near" syntax error on iphone

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am experimenting a problem with sqlite in my iphone app. Read part is ok, but when I try to write to a database using UPADATE command (I try with INSERT too), the sql sentence give me back the error sqlite3_errmsg:

```
Failed. Error is:  near "UP": syntax error
```

The code is:

```
-(void)ratesInfotoDb:(NSString *)idx rate:(NSString*)rate{

    query =@"UPDATE rules set rate = 5 where _id = 1994";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, &statement, nil);

    if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE ) {
        NSLog(@"element added");
        }
    else{
        NSLog( @"Failed. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_database);

}
```

The query command "UPDATE rules set rate = 5 where _id = 1994" (executed directly on a database), works, so I suppose query is corect.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Make sure your database is open.. i haven't seen `sqlite3_open` in your code.

Comment: What is the error message for `INSERT`?

Comment: @CL if the same `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is used, the error for the `INSERT` statement will be: "Failed. Error is:  near "IN": syntax error".

Comment: change iOS version 8.2 check it works or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simple. You are passing the wrong value to the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` function. The 3rd parameter should represent the length of the query string.

The macro `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` has a value of `2` so you are stating that the query is only 2 bytes long which is not true.

Change your call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` as follows:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil);
```

Passing `-1` tells `sqlite3_prepare_v2` to get the actual length of the query (probably by using `strlen`).

BTW - always check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and make sure it returns `SQLITE_OK`.

Comment: I used SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE parameter because -1 is refered to a READONLY database, isn'it?  using your answer the error is:"Failed. Error is:  attempt to write a readonly database"

Comment: The `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` is a value used with the `sqlite3_open_v2` function, not the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` function. Please see the sqlite3 docs at http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html

Comment: Confirm the result code of all of your `sqlite3_...` function calls. Be sure you are opening the write database. Make sure the database is NOT in the resource bundle (that's read-only). Make sure there is actually a row that matches the `where` clause.

Comment: Tx @rmaddy. Data base is open, the row is correct. I am not sure aboute if the database is NOT in the resource bundle. how can I check that?

Comment: What's the path to the db file?

Comment: I copied the database into the project. have I need to do anything else?

Comment: the bunle path is : bundlePath is /var/mobile/Applications/DDD9D/appName.app/classifier.db

Comment: That's the problem. The bundle is read-only. You can't update a db file in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this method...

Your database is not opened. Look at this method for an example of how to do open it properly.

```
-(void)executeQuery:(NSString *)query
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"query Statement Not Compiled");
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Data not Opened");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you think the database is open? The OP's code is using an ivar for the database handle. The database is probable opened beforehand.

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary A database that is not open cannot possibly be the reason for a syntax error.

Comment: @Dharmbir tx. With your code, error not appear. I think It was due to the "SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE" in my code. So no error appear but the database not is updated :(

Answer (score -1):

```
         NSString *status;


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOUR DATABASE NAME.sqlite"]];

    NSLog(@"Database Path %@",dbPath);

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSLog(@"open");

        NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE rules set rate = 5 where _id = 1994"];

        const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            status=@" Updated";
        }

        else
        {
            status=@"Error occured";
        }
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem.